# Calling python script from html/php

Tags: php, python, html

I am trying to make my python code run on website. In my python code, I need to input one image and one video url, like this:

```
import cv2


img = "1.jpg"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-OUhbw-XsTg")
```

So I write a HTML code so that I can input image and video url:

```html
    <html>
    <body>
　   <form action="upload1.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
　   <input type="file" name="file" id="file" /><br/><br/>
     Video URLs:<input type="url" name="url" id="myURL"><br/><br/>
     <button name = "Analyze" type="submit"> Analyze </button>
　     </form>
     </body>
     </html>
```

I want that when I input an image and url, after clicking Analyze it can return the image and url path to python and run the code. I only know how to call python script but don't know how to get and return value to python.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Analyze'])){
    exec("python code.py",$output);
    var_dump($output);
}
?>
```

Can anyone help my how to get the path from HTML and return to python with PHP? Thank you.

Comment: Is `$output` NULL?

Comment: You can pass image and url as arguments. In your python code use `sys.argv` to get the arguments.

Comment: Your code looks good.. you should get the output value of "python code.py" into $output. Can you check what you are getting as output, if your run command directly.